# Heroku Ruby / Rails Cache Webpack + Yarn Between Deploys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I currently have a brand new ruby / rails app setup with webpacker. Every deploy to Heroku takes an additional 30+ seconds to re-install the yarn dependencies (runs `yarn install`).

```
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning "babel-loader@7.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-core@6 || 7 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta || ^7.0.0-rc".
remote:        warning "babel-loader@7.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@2 || 3".
remote:        warning "compression-webpack-plugin@1.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.1.0".
remote:        warning "file-loader@1.1.5" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "postcss-cssnext@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
remote:        warning "rails-erb-loader@5.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "sass-loader@6.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "node-sass@^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "sass-loader@6.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "url-loader@0.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "file-loader@*".
remote:        warning "webpack-manifest-plugin@1.3.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || 2 || 3".
remote:        warning "ajv-keywords@2.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "ajv@^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx@3.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props@^2.0.0".
remote:        warning "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx@3.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx@^6.8.0".
remote:        warning "vue-loader@13.5.0" has incorrect peer dependency "css-loader@*".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server@2.9.7" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 33.50s.
remote:        Webpacker is installed
```

I'm currently using the `heroku/ruby` buildpack on the `heroku-16` stack. 
Any easy way to get the caching to work like it does for bundler?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can add [a second nodejs buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) in addition to your heroku stack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

The nodejs buildpack should support yarn caching as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior).

Comment: Here's a discussion on rails/webpacker which talks about using the nodejs buildpack as well: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/405#issuecomment-332682225

Comment: This doesn't work with Rails. Leads to Heroku installing yarn dependencies twice...

Comment: In the link @DerekHopper posted earlier people had success with deleteing `bin/yarn` from the rails project to prevent rails from installing deps a second time. Maybe you can try out that one and see if it works?
Also probably it is still faster to run yarn install twice, when caching deps works, is it?